# If planeswalkers aren't creatures, how does Gideon's defeat work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Gideon's Defeat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%27s%5d%2b%5bDefeat%5d) says:

> Exile target white creature that's attacking or blocking. If it was a Gideon planeswalker, you gain 5 life.

However the rules also say:

> Planeswalkers are not creatures. Spells and abilities that affect creatures won't affect them.

If planeswalkers are not creatures, you cannot exile them with Gideon's Defeat, and thus you are not gaining any life from it?

Comment: The existing answers have you covered for normal situations but keep in mind that magic is a big game and there are many effects that do weird things. For example, having Mycosynth Lattice on the board turns all permanents into artifacts. An effect like Tezzeret's abilities or Sydri, Galvanic Genius can then turn those artifacts into creatures, at which point Gideon of the Trials would be a 'Legendary Creature Artifact Planeswalker - Gideon Human soldier'.

Comment: Not a full answer so I'm not adding an answer, but many planeswalkers in the game have a "schtick", i.e. some type of generic effect that is associated with their character cards.  For example, Liliana's schtick is that she usually discards and reanimates things, Jace draws cards, Chandra burns things, etc.  Gideon's schtick is that he can become a creature and engage in combat, so a Gideon Planeswalker creature is not at all uncommon.

Answer (score 28):

Planeswalkers *usually* aren't creatures, but planeswalkers can sometimes *turn into* creatures. All iterations of Gideon can turn into a creature—it's kinda his thing—and sometimes other planeswalkers can too, like [Sarkhan, the Dragonspeaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSarkhan%2c%20the%20Dragonspeaker%5d) who can turn into a dragon.

In Amonkhet, the Gideon planeswalker was [Gideon of the Trials](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%20of%20the%20Trials%5d). His second loyalty ability says:

> Until end of turn, Gideon of the Trials becomes a 4/4 Human Soldier creature with indestructible that’s still a planeswalker. Prevent all damage that would be dealt to him this turn.

After using this ability his type line would say: *Legendary Planeswalker Creature — Gideon Human Soldier.* This makes him a legal target for "target creature", so if he then attacks, he'll be a legal target for [Gideon's Defeat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%27s%5d%2b%5bDefeat%5d).

Since you usually can't activate loyalty abilities on someone else's turn, it's rare you'll see Gideon *blocking* like this, but if somehow that happens he'll be a legal target for Gideon's Defeat then too.

Comment: The most common way for Gideon to be blocking is probably some kind of mind control effect.

Comment: @Erik Mind control probably wouldn't do it. Chad still stops being a creature EOT. Effects like Sundial of the Infinite or Teferi, Temporal Archmage's -10 ability do work, allowing you to respectively keep creature Gideon around forever or to turn him into a creature at instant speed.

Comment: Mycosynth Lattice + March of the Machines would allow Gideon (and all planeswalkers for that matter) to block, as it turns Gideon into a Legendary Artifact Creature Planeswalker permanently.

Comment: @Valthek An instant speed steal like Ray of Command will also do the trick. Also Sundial doesn't work, as the cleanup step still happens.

Comment: The reminder text for [Sundial of the Infinite](https://scryfall.com/card/m12/218) includes *'Damage wears off, and “this turn” and “until end of turn” effects end.'*

Comment: You can block with Gideon with the emblem from Teferi, Temporal Archmage

Answer (score 8):

Planeswalkers are not *automatically* creatures, but there are effects that can make them *become* creatures.

For example, [Gideon Jura](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%20Jura%5d) has an ability that says:

> Until end of turn, Gideon Jura becomes a 6/6 Human Soldier creature that's still a planeswalker. Prevent all damage that would be dealt to him this turn.

After this ability is used, if Gideon Jura attacks or blocks, he would be a valid target for Gideon's Defeat.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be because -as the others have stated-, some Planeswalkers have the ability to become creatures. Specifically, all Gideon Planeswalker Cards have this ability. This would be the basis of why this card was created: To target specifically Gideon to give you a boost of Life.

This is the same for any of the other Planeswalker defeat cards in Hour of Devastation. They all have specific requirements that relate to certain perks that each of the named Planeswalkers have.

Comment: Downvote... can you give me a reason?

Comment: Probably because your answer adds nothing to the other answers whigh were posted before yours, you even admit as much with your "-as the others have stated-"

Answer (score 0):

In magic, planeswalkers are not considered creatures, this is true. But they can be made creatures by other effects. Most specifically the Gideon planeswalkers all have an ability that "animates" them, makes them into creatures, from the original [Gideon Jura](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%20Jura%5d) with his ability:

> 0: Until end of turn, Gideon Jura becomes a 6/6 Human Soldier creature that's still a planeswalker. Prevent all damage that would be dealt to him this turn.

To the most recent, [Gideon of the Trials](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%20of%20the%20Trials%5d) with his ability:

> 0: Until end of turn, Gideon of the Trials becomes a 4/4 Human Soldier creature with indestructible that's still a planeswalker. Prevent all damage that would be dealt to him this turn.

While these are active, Gideon can attack like any other creature, following the normal creature rules, untapped and not summoning sick etc. The abilities only last for the turn, so they don't usually allow Gideon to block, unless there is a way to activate them on opponents turns, like through the emblem of [Teferi, Temporal Archmage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Temporal%20Archmage%5d).

There are other ways to animate planeswalkers, usually that involves making them some other card type that can be easily made a creature. The common way to do this is with a card called [Mycosynth Lattice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMycosynth%20Lattice%5d), which makes everything, planeswalkers included, into an artifact, and there are many cards that can turn artifacts into creatures, like [March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarch%20of%20the%20Machines%5d) or [Animate Artifact](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnimate%20Artifact%5d), even some planewsalkers themselves, like [Tezzeret, Agent of Bolas](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTezzeret%2c%20Agent%20of%20Bolas%5d) could turn themselves into a creature.

Comment: Sorry, but what is different about this answer than all previous answers? It literally looks like you added them all together as well as comments from over a year ago. Maybe you can try to change it up a bit, add something new?

Comment: @CodeMaverick The other answers all reference ONLY the planeswalker abilities as ways to become creatures, there are other ways, as I mentioned. You are correct that they are in comments, but many people don't read comments, expecting the answer to be definitive and corrected based on comments.